# NDK JNI functions call

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I just started using NDK, since my Android SDK code did not give satisfactory results, though I have never tried to code in C/C++.
Until now, I generated the headers of my two native functions, `fft_transform()` and `convolve()`.

I want to have use of the code written [here](https://www.nayuki.io/res/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages/fft.c).
The problem is that `fft_transform` calls other C functions, and being called itself in another C function.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_ffttest_FFTActivity_transform
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdoubleArray real, jdoubleArray imag, jint n)
{
if (n == 0)
    return 1;
else if ((n & (n - 1)) == 0)  // Is power of 2
    return transform_radix2(real, imag, n);
else  // More complicated algorithm for arbitrary sizes
    return transform_bluestein(real, imag, n);
}
```

Should I declare the non-JNI functions in the header as they are, or change them to JNI functions?
How to add `JNI *env` and `jobj obj` variables in the non-JNI functions?

For example:

```
int inverse_transform(double real[], double imag[], size_t n) {
    return Java_com_example_ffttest_FFTActivity_transform(env, obj, imag, real, n);
}
```

Please consider that I never used C/C++ neither NDK before starting to vote down.

Comment: are you trying to send back results from c++ to java?

Comment: yes the result of the convolution will be sent back to java.

Comment: The Java version of the algorithm was not fast enough for you? http://www.nayuki.io/res/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages/Fft.java

Comment: Thx but that was long time ago. Now, it works well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Java method FFTActivity.transform(..) seems to have no return type. Therefore you can not return something in it's JNI implementation like you do: `if (n == 0) return 1;`
   Change the Java method and re-create/update your JNI headers accordingly.
2. Use Java_com_example_ffttest_FFTActivity_transform to convert from Java JNI types into C/C++ types used in the C/C++ implementation you want to use. Check JNI documentation for the available functions for doing so (see e.g. GetDoubleArrayElements method).
3. You should not mix up regular C/C++ functions with JNI C/C++ function. In general this possible but a bit complicated. Therefore you should not call the JNI function anywhere in your c/C++ code. This method is only called from the Java side of your application.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification @Robert, So now i need to "re-write" the functions myself. i cannot call a JNI function inside another JNI function either?

Comment: That should be possible but it does only make sense in only a few cases. Better handle it that way to implement the functionality in a plain C/C++ function that is called from a JNI function.